# How to deploy application that depends on dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, macos, dynamic-linking, install-name-tool

I am developing an application that uses the GStreamer library. In order to ease deployment I would like to collect all the GStreamer libraries in a local bundle. For this I wrote a little script that does the following:

- recursively traverse dependencies (using `otool -L`)
- copy all dependencies to a local directory
- make all the dependency paths relative to @executable_path (using `install_name_tool`)

(If you're interested you can have a look at the [Ruby script](http://code.google.com/p/stacked-crooked/source/browse/trunk/Utilities/localize_dependencies.rb).)

However, I'm now seeing runtime errors on the `gst_init` call:

```
(process:22843): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2458: initialization assertion failed, use g_type_init() prior to this function

(process:22843): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed
```

These errors only occur if I use the localized libraries.

Are there certain 'common pitfalls' when it comes to using install_name_tool? Does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong? If you need to know certain details then feel free to ask.

**Update**
I changed a few things:

- For the dependent libraries I now only change the dylib paths and not the id (only use `install_name_tool -change` and not `install_name_tool -id`).
- For the main library I set the id value relative to the executable path (`@executable_name/components/Video.dylib`).

These two changes make it work. However it is not yet clear to me why it works. I have some trouble understanding the meaning of the "id" property. It seems to be identifier in the form of a pathname. Why did changing it for the dependent libraries cause runtime errors? I'll try to find answers to those questions with some further experimentation...

Comment: Could it be that you influence the load order for the respective dependencies by accident?

Comment: @gf: I don't think so, but I'll keep it in mind. I've made some progress, check the edit if you're interested.

Comment: Aren't you building an .app bundle?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should consider a static compilation of your code.
this will attach your dependencies to your program much better

if you're using gcc just add `-static`

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer is a complex system, with a lot of dependencies. Using tools will find out shared libraries directly required by GStreamer, but they'll surely miss libraries loaded dynamically, configuration files, and also translation data.

[This site probably contains some usefull info](http://codeanticode.wordpress.com/2009/04/03/gstreamer-installer-for-macosx/) on creating a stand-alone GStreamer package, which could simplify the bundling prpcess.